# Node.js drawing game based off of my state diagram

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, node.js, state-machine, ecmascript-6

I really want to have a nice design pattern for my Node.js project. [This is my state diagram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6UiRKVrdltHOTBYU3BGcEpldW8/view?usp=sharing). As I'm coding this, I'm wondering if it's better to separate state logic from the class? So instead I would only have my class be responsible for initial construction and then emitting state changes which get handled elsewhere.

```
'use strict';

var Games = {};

class PublicGameRoom {

    constructor(players) {
        // Set players prop, return error if not array
        if (Array.isArray(players)) this.players = shuffle(players);
        else throw 'Attempted to create game without correct players param';

        // Available game states
        this.game_states = ['ESTABLISHED', 'START', 'DRAW', 'OVER', 'CHOOSE_WINNER', 'DISPLAY_WINNER', 'TERMINATE'];
        this.game_state = this.game_states[0];
        // Set min and max players
        this.min_players = 3;
        this.max_players = 8;
        // Set the first judge
        this.judge = players[0];
        // Create and set a time id for game_room
        this._id = generateID();
        // Create a socket channel for game_room and subscribe players, callback to startGame when players are connected
        this.game_socket = createGameSocket(this.players, this.playerDisconnects, this.startGame);
        // Add the game to the Games map
        Games[this._id] = this;
    }

    // TODO: Not sure if these get/set are needed
    // set gameState(state) {
    //     this.game_state = state;
    // }

    // get gameState() {
    //     return this.game_state;
    // }

    // When a player presses leave game
    playerExits(playerToRemove) {
        // Delete player from players array
        this.players.splice(this.players.indexOf(playerToRemove), 1);

        // If theres not enough players to continue, terminate game
        if (this.players.length < this.min_players) this.game_state = this.game_states[6];
        // Else disconnect the player from the game socket
        else this.game_socket.kickPlayer(playerToRemove);
    }

    // When a player disconnects without warning, e.g. closes window
    playerDisconnects(playerToRemove) {
        // Delete player from players array
        this.players.splice(this.players.indexOf(playerToRemove), 1);
        // If theres not enough players to continue, terminate game
        if (this.players.length < this.min_players) this.game_state = this.game_states[6];
    }

    // Sets a new judge by popping the end player
    newJudge () {
        this.judge = this.players.pop();
        this.players = this.players.unshift(this.judge);
    }

    // Begin the game by prompting judge to pick a phrase
    startGame() {
        this.game_state = this.game_states[1];
        let phrases = generatePhrases();
        showJudge(phrases);
    }
}

var x = new PublicGameRoom([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(x.gameState);
console.log(x.players);
x.playerExits(1);

/**
Helper Functions
*/
function createGameSocket() {
    return {
        kickPlayer: function(player) {
            console.log('kicked', player);
        }
    };
}

// Generate a random id for the game_room
function generateID() {
    var id_length = 8;
    var timestamp = new Date();

    // number of milliseconds since 1970
    return timestamp.valueOf();
}

// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (included)
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// The de-facto unbiased shuffle algorithm is the Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) Shuffle.
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

// Creates a list of randomly generated phrases
function generatePhrases() {
    return ['old duck', 'pregnant paperclip', 'fat chair', 'trendy turtles', 'fluffy cups'];
}

// Show the judge the phrases and prompt him to chose amongst them
function showJudge(phrases) {

}

// Kill the game by deleting it from the game map
function killGame(gameID) {
    delete Games[gameID];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can seperate the queue from the game. The queue will have one statechart, and whenever there are enough players it will start a new game (which will have a different statechart). This will simplify the design (and allow multiple games to be played concurrently!).

The queue has two states:

- NOT_ENOUGH: the number of players is smaller than the minimum required for game.
- ENOUGH: there are enough players for a game, but less than the maximum possible. In this case, a game will be started in 30 seconds or when the maximum number of players is reached.

So you'll want a `Queue` class which holds an array of players, and handles players joining and leaving the queue: (`options` include minimum and maximum number of players for a game and the timeout)

```
class Queue {
    constructor(options) {
        this.players = [];
        this.options = options;
    }

    playerJoined(player) { /* TODO */}

    playerLeft(player) { /* TODO */}
}
```

Currently, you handle state by using strings:

```
this.state = 'NOT_ENOUGH';
```

Unfortunately, the only thing you can do with this string is to compare it to another one: you can test whether `this.state` equals to `'NOT_ENOUGH'` or to `'ENOUGH'`. The string isn't really a state, it's only an identifier that tells Queue what the current state is; Queue still has to handle all the possible states and the string can't do anything to help.

The solution (called the **State Pattern**) is to use a *state object* which can handle the state it represents. Let's start with the `'NOT_ENOUGH'` state: we'll make a class to represent this state, and let it handle this state by responding appropriately to the two possible events:

```
class NotEnough {
    constructor(queue) {
        this.queue = queue; /* the queue this state belongs to */
    }

    playerJoined(player) {
        queue.players.push(player);
    }

    playerLeft(player) {
        queue.players.splice(queue.players.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
}
```

Now, instead of using a string, Queue can use an *actual state* and let it handle the logic involved with it:

```
class Queue {
    constructor(options) {
        this.players = [];
        this.options = options;
        this.state = new NotEnough(this);
    }

    playerJoined(player) {
        this.state.playerJoined(player);
    }

    playerLeft(player) {
        this.state.playerLeft(player);
    }
}
```

Now let's add another class to represent the `'ENOUGH'` state:

```
class Enough {
    constructor(queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    playerJoined(player) {
        queue.players.push(player);
    }

    playerLeft(player) {
        queue.players.splice(queue.players.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
}
```

The next step is implementing transitions between states. Each state will be responsible for choosing the correct next state.

```
class NotEnough {
    /* ... */
    playerJoined(player) {
        queue.players.push(player);
        if(queue.players.length >= queue.options.minNumPlayers) {
            queue.setState(new Enough(queue));
        }
    }
}

class Enough {
    /* ... */
    playerJoined(player) {
        queue.players.push(player);
        if(queue.players.length == queue.options.maxNumPlayers) {
            queue.startGame();
            queue.setState(new NotEnough(queue));
        }
    }

    playerLeft(player) {
        queue.players.splice(queue.players.indexOf(player), 1);
        if(queue.players.length < queue.options.minNumPlayers) {
            queue.setState(new NotEnough(queue));
        }
    }
}
```

This required adding a `setState` method to `Queue`:

```
setState(state) {
    this.state = state;
}
```

Finally, `Enough` needs to set a timer so it can start the game automatically when it expires:

```
class Enough {
    constructor(queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.startTimer();
    }

    playerJoined(player) {
        queue.players.push(player);
        if(queue.players.length == queue.options.maxNumPlayers) {
            this.cancelTimer();
            this.startGame();
        }
    }

    playerLeft(player) {
        queue.players.splice(queue.players.indexOf(player), 1);
        if(queue.players.length < queue.options.minNumPlayers) {
            this.cancelTimer();
            queue.setState(new NotEnough(queue));
        }
    }

    startGame() {
        queue.startGame();
        queue.setState(new NotEnough(queue));
    }

    startTimer() {
        this.timeoutId = window.setTimeout(this.onTimeout.bind(this), queue.options.startGameTimeout);
    }

    cancelTimer() {
        window.clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
        this.timeoutId = undefined;
    }

    onTimeout() {
        this.startGame();
    }
}
```

([Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/hgycc1j9/) tested with Chrome)

Notice `Queue` is much simpler now because it lets its states handle the incoming events. (The code can be refactored now by extracting repeated code to new functions, and extracting code common to both states to the `Queue` class)

Now you need to change `queue.startGame` to instantiate a `Game` object.

Add a `Game` class and implement its state chart using the State Pattern. `Game` will have a function for each possible event (e.g. judge selected phrase, time out, winner selected, player left) and delegate to its state. Each state will handle the events that can occur in it. Start with a simplified game with only two states: Drawing (with the phrase selected randomly when the game starts) and Game Over (winner selected randomly and shown, then game restarts after 10s). Then add the other states and events one by one.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks so much, great design pattern. My greatest concern with implementing the design is dereferencing of Games from the games map. Right now, Im thinking just call `delete Games[game._id]`. I've been told that the GC wont pick up the game object if anything is refrencing it. Would class be refrencing the game and thus make dereferencing harder?

Comment: You need a clean up function in `Game` that unregisters all callbacks (methods of the `Game` object) that were registered on socket events. Then after you delete the reference from the global game map, there will be no more references to the Game and it will be garbage collected. The class itself doesn't reference game objects.

Comment: if you have `class Drawing` with a constructor that accepts the game object, doesnt that mean its referencing the game?

Comment: Can you give an example what you mean by methods that were registered on socket events

Comment: @DanielKobe When the `Drawing` object is no longer used, the reference to `Game` will be removed. Sockets are used in JavaScript by using callbacks - search for examples of using sockets with whatever library you want to use for sockets (e.g. Socket.IO). After you have working code that uses sockets, you can post it and ask if there are any memory leaks.

Comment: Hey @DanielKobe, if you liked this answer, how about swinging it an upvote ;-)